# PHP: Detect if string contains JavaScript/jQuery code inside and delete that part of code

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a variable in PHP which contains different HTML code. Sometimes i find in this HTML code parts of javascript code or jquery code. This extra code may or may not have the `<script>` tag. So for example i might find jquery functions surrounded in a `<p>` tag.

Is there a way to detect this javascript/jquery code in the string and delete?

Comment: Be wary of using regular expressions for this, they are notoriously bad for parsing HTML. Best bet will be to use a full HTML parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use HTMLPurifier to scrub bad code out of user input.

http://htmlpurifier.org/